# Remove querystring from URL

Tags: javascript

What is an easy way to remove the querystring from a Path in Javascript?
I have seen a plugin for Jquery that uses window.location.search. I can not do that: The URL in my case is a variable that is set from AJAX.

```
var testURL = '/Products/List?SortDirection=dsc&Sort=price&Page=3&Page2=3&SortOrder=dsc'
```

> Edit after 13 years

At some point in the last decade Javascript got some Url handling.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

Removing specific param:

```js
const url = new URL('https://example.com?foo=1&bar=2');
url.searchParams.delete("foo");
console.log(url.href);
```

Removing all params:

```js
const url = new URL('https://example.com?foo=1&bar=2');
url.search = "";
console.log(url.href);
```

Answer (score 439):

An easy way to get this is:

```
function getPathFromUrl(url) {
  return url.split("?")[0];
}
```

For those who also wish to **remove the hash** (not part of the original question) **when no querystring exists**, that requires a little bit more:

```
function stripQueryStringAndHashFromPath(url) {
  return url.split("?")[0].split("#")[0];
}
```

**EDIT**

@caub (originally @crl) suggested a simpler combo that works for both query string and hash (though it uses RegExp, in case anyone has a problem with that):

```
function getPathFromUrl(url) {
  return url.split(/[?#]/)[0];
}
```

Comment: +1... Actually split() is better than substring() in this case.

Comment: Marginal optimisation if it matters (probably not): `split('?', 1)[0]`.

Comment: @ChristianVielma: This `?` is a string literal, not a regular expression.

Comment: @Robusto I'm sorry, my bad... I was checking it in Java (which interprets it as a regex) :(

Comment: function fnRemoveQsParameter(url, parameter) {
  return url.split("?")[parameter].split("#")[parameter];
 }

Comment: Hey Robusto, and why not `.split(/[?#]/)[0]`?

Comment: @crl: Not bad. All that biking must clear your head. :-)

Comment: This answer is not correct. The original question is to remove a query string from the URL. However, in a URL that has both query params as well as fragment, the answers here will remove both.

Comment: @UtsavChatterjee: The OP made no mention of fragments. That was brought up in a comment. The fact that the OP accepted this answer indicates that the bare path was really what he was interested in.

Answer (score 37):

**2nd Update:** In attempt to provide a comprehensive answer, I am benchmarking the three methods proposed in the various answers.

```
var testURL = '/Products/List?SortDirection=dsc&Sort=price&Page=3&Page2=3';
var i;

// Testing the substring method
i = 0;
console.time('10k substring');
while (i < 10000) {
    testURL.substring(0, testURL.indexOf('?'));
    i++;
}
console.timeEnd('10k substring');

// Testing the split method
i = 0;
console.time('10k split');
while (i < 10000) {
    testURL.split('?')[0]; 
    i++;
}
console.timeEnd('10k split');

// Testing the RegEx method
i = 0;
var re = new RegExp("[^?]+");
console.time('10k regex');
while (i < 10000) {
    testURL.match(re)[0]; 
    i++;
}
console.timeEnd('10k regex');
```

Results in Firefox 3.5.8 on Mac OS X 10.6.2:

```
10k substring:  16ms
10k split:      25ms
10k regex:      44ms
```

Results in Chrome 5.0.307.11 on Mac OS X 10.6.2:

```
10k substring:  14ms
10k split:      20ms
10k regex:      15ms
```

Note that the substring method is inferior in functionality as it returns a blank string if the URL does not contain a querystring. The other two methods would return the full URL, as expected. However it is interesting to note that the substring method is the fastest, especially in Firefox.

---

**1st UPDATE:** Actually the split() method [suggested by Robusto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540969/remove-querystring-from-url/2541083#2541083) is a better solution that the one I suggested earlier, since it will work even when there is no querystring:

```
var testURL = '/Products/List?SortDirection=dsc&Sort=price&Page=3&Page2=3';
testURL.split('?')[0];    // Returns: "/Products/List"

var testURL2 = '/Products/List';
testURL2.split('?')[0];    // Returns: "/Products/List"
```

---

**Original Answer:**

```
var testURL = '/Products/List?SortDirection=dsc&Sort=price&Page=3&Page2=3';
testURL.substring(0, testURL.indexOf('?'));    // Returns: "/Products/List"
```

Comment: O_O Very comprehensive indeed, but… why? The most flexible and appropriate method obviously wins, speed is of absolutely no concern here.

Comment: @deceze: Just for curiosity... And because there was an argument about the performance of the regex method in the comments of the Angus' answer.

Comment: Very interesting, Daniel. And if I ever have to do 10K URL parses on a page I'm going to seek another line of work. :)

Comment: I'm actually a bit blown away that one can do 10k regex matches in 44ms. In the future, I think I will be inclined to use them more.

Answer (score 30):

This may be an old question but I have tried this method to remove query params. Seems to work smoothly for me as I needed a reload as well combined with removing of query params.

```
window.location.href = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname;
```

Also since I am using simple string addition operation I am guessing the performance will be good. But Still worth comparing with snippets in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2540992/5617140)

Comment: Best solution IMO. Are there are downsides or cases where this won't work?

Comment: The reason is that the OP specifically states that they can't use window.location and have to operate on a bare string exclusively.

Answer (score 22):

```js
var u = new URL('https://server.de/test?q#h')
u.hash = ''
u.search = ''
console.log(u.toString())
```

Comment: This is the only valid answer in this thread.

Comment: This is better and even works in nodejs, but the performance is just a little worse if you have to process many thousands of URLs per second.

Answer (score 7):

I can understand how painful things were before, In modern days you can get this super easily like below

```
let url = new URL('https://example.com?foo=1&bar=2&foo=3');
let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);

// Delete the foo parameter.
params.delete('foo'); //Query string is now: 'bar=2'

// now join the query param and host
let newUrl =  url.origin + '/' + params.toString();
```

Comment: `let params = url.searchParams` suffices.

Answer (score 4):

```
var path = "path/to/myfile.png?foo=bar#hash";

console.log(
    path.replace(/(\?.*)|(#.*)/g, "")
);
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is you can do as follows

```
public static String stripQueryStringAndHashFromPath(String uri) {
 return uri.replaceAll(("(\\?.*|\\#.*)"), "");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An approach using the standard `URL`:

```
/**
 * @param {string} path - A path starting with "/"
 * @return {string}
 */
function getPathname(path) {
  return new URL(`http://_${path}`).pathname
}

getPathname('/foo/bar?cat=5') // /foo/bar
```

Comment: @Brad what does the protocol matter when all he does is returning the pathname afterwards?

Comment: @The Fool - the `new URL()` will fail with 'Invalid URL` error message otherwise

Answer (score 1):

If you're into RegEx....

```
var newURL = testURL.match(new RegExp("[^?]+"))
```

Comment: the regexp is slow one - go with the easy fast way.

Comment: Not for this operation it isn't. 1000 ops on a long URL takes 5ms in firefox

Comment: @Angus: Your loop is giving you "A script may be busy..." because you forgot to increment `a++;`. Fixing the tests, in my Firefox 3.6 on an iMac 2.93Ghz Core 2 Duo, I get 8ms for the RegEx, and 3ms for the split method... Nevertheless +1 for the answer, because it is still another option.

Comment: thanks - I fixed it a few mins ago! - but the point is when you are talking 0.000005 seconds even for the reg exp operation, performance is not an issue for any solution :-)

Comment: `match()` returns an object. You probably don't want that. Call `toString()` on it (or `+''`).

Comment: Bob - good catch. Actually it returns an array of matches - an Array of strings in this case. So testURL.match(new RegExp("[^?]+"))[0] does it

Answer (score 1):

If using backbone.js (which contains `url anchor` as route), url `query string` may appear:

1. before `url anchor`:

   ```
   var url = 'http://example.com?a=1&b=3#routepath/subpath';
   ```
2. after `url anchor`:

   ```
   var url = 'http://example.com#routepath/subpath?a=1&b=3';
   ```

Solution:

```
window.location.href.replace(window.location.search, '');
// run as: 'http://example.com#routepath/subpath?a=1&b=3'.replace('?a=1&b=3', '');
```