# How to check if url has no query string in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am editing a form in WordPress. I want my jquery script to execute when the url has no query string.

The url should not have a query string like this: http://127.0.0.1/mybetabizopi/login/?action=lostpassword

I only want my script to run when the url is like this or has no query string:
http://127.0.0.1/mybetabizopi/login/

This is my current script:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(function() {


    j('#login #user_login').attr('placeholder', 'Username');
    j('#login #user_pass').attr('placeholder', 'Password');

    j('#login #user_login').addClass('form-control');
    j('#login #user_pass').addClass('form-control');

    j('#login #loginform label').wrap( "<div class='input-group'></div>" );


    j('#login .form-control').each(function() {
        j(this).insertAfter(j(this).parent());
    });

    j('#loginform .input-group > label').remove();

    j('<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>').insertBefore('#user_login');

    j('<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>').insertBefore('#user_pass');


});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please check this answer (by Felix Kling): http://stackoverflow.com/a/5817566/4287861

Comment: This blog post could be useful: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html

Comment: @RanHassid that's for getting the URL without the querystring, not checking if there is a querystring

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `indexOf` on the `window.location.href` to check if there is a `?` character.

Note that you can name the jQuery instance provided to the document.ready handler as you need, so you can still use the `$` variable within that function scope, even through the global `$` no longer points to jQuery. Also, you can make your jQuery code more efficient by caching and re-using your selectors. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf('?') == -1) { // no querystring exists
    $('#login #user_login').attr('placeholder', 'Username').addClass('form-control');
    $('#login #user_pass').attr('placeholder', 'Password').addClass('form-control');

    $('#login #loginform label').wrap("<div class='input-group'></div>");

    $('#login .form-control').each(function() {
      $(this).insertAfter($(this).parent());
    });

    $('#loginform .input-group > label').remove();

    $('<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>').insertBefore('#user_login');
    $('<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>').insertBefore('#user_pass');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using search property of location object.

```
var querystring=window.location.search;
alert(querystring);
```

It will return the query string of URL, Use it to check if URL has query string or not, and execute the jQuery code only if it's blank.

Like this,

```
if(querystring=="") {
    // Execute jQuery code.
}
```

Comment: You should be a senior developer. Thank you sir

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use Javascripts `location.search` for that purpose like so:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var j = jQuery.noConflict();
            j(function() {

                var hasQuery    = (location.search && location.search != undefined)?true : false;
                if(!hasQuery){

                    j('#login #user_login').attr('placeholder', 'Username');
                    j('#login #user_pass').attr('placeholder', 'Password');                 
                    j('#login #user_login').addClass('form-control');
                    j('#login #user_pass').addClass('form-control');                    
                    j('#login #loginform label').wrap( "<div class='input-group'></div>" );


                    j('#login .form-control').each(function() {
                        j(this).insertAfter(j(this).parent());
                    });

                    j('#loginform .input-group > label').remove();

                    j('<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>').insertBefore('#user_login');

                    j('<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>').insertBefore('#user_pass');                 
                }               
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much you're a guru

Answer (score 1):

Hi use below function to check whether querystring exist or not

```
function checkQueryStringExists()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    if(hashes.length>0)
        return true;
    else 
    return false;
}
```