# Using split to get only the URL without query string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to split the website name and get only URL without the query string
example:
www.xyz.com/.php?id=1

the URL can be of any length so I want to split to get the URL to only 
xyz.com

able to split the URL and getting xyz.com/php?id=1
but how do I end the split and get only xyz.com

`var domain2 = document.getElementById("domain_id").value.split("w.")[1];`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any method to get the URL without query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817505/is-there-any-method-to-get-the-url-without-query-string)

Comment: @Charmander already gone through this, didn't found any solution there.

Comment: The query string is _part_ of the URL; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL. The bit you want (www.xyz.com) is the "host".

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
new URL()
```

for example -

```
var urlData = new URL("http://www.example.org/.php?id=1")
```

and than

```
urlData.host
```

which will only return the hostname

Comment: I like that. Very. Much. However, this won't work if the page url needs to be taken from within a routed page. e.g. www.xyz.com/users.php?id=1

Comment: i am trying to get the input through the form, so how can i use documen.getElementById in with this answer?

Comment: Try:
var domain = new URL(document.getElementById("domain_id").value).host;

Comment: `.host` will include `www.`, the OP mentioned he only wants `xyz.com`. Also, his example URL doesn't contain the schema (the `http://` part).

Comment: @Titus exactly i need only xyz.com

Comment: you can try - 
`var domain = new URL("http://" + document.getElementById("domain_id").value).host.replace("www.", "");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regex with [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to capture the host in the way you want:

```js
var url = 'www.xyz.com/.php?id=1';
var host = url.match(/www.(.*)\//)[1];

console.log(host)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding it to other, you can also use this regex expression to capture everything up until the query string "?" like so;

This will also work if you want to grab any sub pages from url before the query string

```js
var exp = new RegExp('^.*(?=([\?]))');
var url = exp.exec("www.xyz.com/.php?id=1");
var host = url[0];

console.log(host);
```