# urlSearchParams not updating the url

Tags: javascript, search, pagination, url-parameters, urlsearchparams

I am trying to add search and page to my url for searching and pagination on a page.

```
 const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
if(!urlParams.has('search'){
   urlParams.append('search', question);
}
if(!urlParams.has('page'){
   urlParams.append('page', pageIndex);
}
```

This appears to do nothing to the actual url.
But when I call urlParams.toString()
then I can see that they have been added, but they are not in the actual url in the browser.

I'm using Chrome 107, so it should support it.
Am I missing something?

The documentation has not helped me so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it does nothing with the actual URL, you are creating a URLParameters Object and updating it. what you are missing is:

```js
window.loacation.search = urlParams.toString()
```

it will change the query string in the browser URL and reloads the page.

**if you are not interested in reloading the page**, you can use `history` DOM object

```js
let url = new URL(window.location.href);
if(!(url.searchParams.has('search'))){
   url.searchParams.append('search', question);
}
if(!(url.searchParams.has('page'))){
   url.searchParams.append('page', pageIndex);
}
history.pushState({},'',url.href);
```

finally, if you want to update the `page` and `search` params anyway, you can use the `url.searchParams.set()` method, like:

```js
url.searchParams.set('page', pageIndex);
```

it will append the parameter if it does not exist, and will update it if it does, without throwing exceptions.

Comment: Note the typo in `window.loacation.search`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

First, retrieve the current `path`. Then, append the `urlParams` to the retrieved path and use `history.pushState()` to set the new URL.

```js
const question = "the question";
const pageIndex = 3;

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

if (! urlParams.has('search')) {
   urlParams.append('search', question);
}

if (! urlParams.has('page')) {
   urlParams.append('page', pageIndex);
}

const path = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
const newURL = `${path}?${urlParams}`;

history.pushState({}, '', newURL);
```

Sources:

- [MDN - URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)
- [MDN - History.pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)
- [Get the URL without query string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5817548)