# How to get the URL without any parameters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

If I use:

```
alert(window.location.href);
```

I get everything including query strings. Is there a way to just get the main url part, for example:

```
http://mysite.com/somedir/somefile/
```

instead of

```
http://mysite.com/somedir/somefile/?foo=bar&loo=goo
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove querystring from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540969/remove-querystring-from-url)

Answer (score 411, accepted):

This is possible, but you'll have to build it manually from the [`location` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location):

```
location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to supply the location.protocol as all modern browsers (including IE6) will automatically inherit the current protocol.  ie: `'//' + location.host + location.pathname`

Comment: @JonnyReeves If you're using it in the current document, that's true: good point. There are occasions when it might be necessary, e.g. if outputting the URL as plain text.

Comment: @lonesomeday **Beautiful!** I used to hack it with `<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] ?>`. Since I was always in a PHP environment anyway. [$_SERVER](http://php.net/reserved.variables.server)

Comment: You don't HAVE to do it this way, as the response implies.

Comment: @lonesomeday your response implies it's the only way, which it isn't.

Comment: It's missing port, so this will return incorrect result for page `http://www.example.com:8080/asdf.html?foo=bar`

Comment: You can save a few characters with `location.origin`, which I believe also addresses @izogfif's concern.

Comment: @Coderer `location.origin` doesn't work for local links: instead of `file://` it gives you `null`.

Comment: both this method and `location.origin` handles not special cases like `javascript:void(0)` which would not be unusual when traversing `href`s of links and buttons.

Comment: @MeowCat2012 That's fair (even though `javascript:` links are not generally good practice). If they're around, a different approach would be needed.

Comment: Maybe I should replace them with `#`s... And hello! SoF is really one of those rare places that 10-year-old accounts can be still active. Feels like time travelling. Sorry bothering you to look at a thread that one could already forgotten over years...

Comment: @MeowCat2012 Yeah, I'm nowhere near as active as I once was, but I still want to take care of my old answers. (And FWIW, an `a` element with a `href` with only a hash will still show all the appropriate `host`, `pathname` etc. properties.)

Answer (score 260):

Every answer is rather convoluted. Here:

```
var url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
```

Even if a ? isn't present, it'll still return the first argument, which will be your full URL, minus query string.

It's also protocol-agnostic, meaning you could even use it for things like ftp, itunes.etc.

Comment: in case you need to remove the anchors `window.location.href.split(/[?#]/)[0];`

Comment: indeed _every_ answer is rather convoluted

Comment: @mehmet all ears if you have a simpler approach :)

Comment: @Oddman, I absolutely don't remember what I was thinking then, but I guess that might be an affirmative statement :))

Comment: @Vishal--JAVA--CQ "better" is subjective, but it's simpler.

Comment: This approach is fine, it's just not any less convoluted than the others. You should remove the first line that implies otherwise, and then mark all these comments for deletion (including this one).

Comment: @Chris na, completely disagree.

Comment: In case you need to redirect from urlparams page to non URL params page: ```if (window.location.href.includes("?")) {
  var redirect_url = window.location.href.split("?")[0];
  window.location.replace(redirect_url);
}```

Answer (score 42):

I'm LATE to the party, but I had to solve this recently, figured I'd share the wealth.

```
const url = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname
//http://example.com/somedir/somefile/
```

`window.location.origin` will give you the base url, in our test case: `http://example.com`

`window.location.pathname` will give you the route path (after the base url), in our test case `/somedir/somefile`

**SOLUTION 2**

You can simply do the following to get rid of the query parameters.

`const url = window.location.href.split('?')[0]`

Comment: Solution 2 is not complete and will include the hashes (#) if come before the QSPs.

Answer (score 15):

Use `indexOf`

```
var url = "http://mysite.com/somedir/somefile/?aa";

if (url.indexOf("?")>-1){
url = url.substr(0,url.indexOf("?"));
}
```

Comment: It doesn't remove #.

Answer (score 13):

Use the [`URL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) constructor, then extract and concatenate the origin and pathname. This will automatically strip the search (aka query) parameters from the url, leaving the scheme, domain, port and pathname only.

```js
const url = new URL('http://example.com/somedir/?foo=bar');
console.log(url.origin + url.pathname);
```

As a note, this type of transformation is usually referred to as normalization, specifically in this case [URI Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_normalization). There may already exist libraries that accomplish this more robustly with more options in your environment.

Answer (score 11):

You can concat `origin` and `pathname`, if theres present a port such as `example.com:80`, that will be included as well.

```
location.origin + location.pathname
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work with Microsoft Internet Explorer <= 10: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/origin

Answer (score 10):

Just one more alternative using URL

```
var theUrl = new URL(window.location.href);
theUrl.search = ""; //Remove any params
theUrl //as URL object
theUrl.href //as a string
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a regular expression: `window.location.href.match(/^[^\#\?]+/)[0]`

Answer (score 4):

```
var url = "tp://mysite.com/somedir/somefile/?foo=bar&loo=goo"    

url.substring(0,url.indexOf("?"));
```

Comment: This presumes, that parameter is defined. Much better is `url.split('?')[0]`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) you can take just the properties you're interested in from the `window` object i.e.

```
protocol + '//' + hostname + pathname
```

Comment: You lose the port number with your suggestion, lonesomeday's solution is better in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
window.location.origin + window.location.pathname
```