# Check for current URL, return true even if there are URL arguments

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm checking for a very specific pattern in URLs so that a set of code is only executed on the correct type of page. Currently, I've got something like:

`/^http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/(?:example\/[^\/]+\/?)?$/;`

So, it'll return `true` for `example.com` and `example.com/example/anythinghere/`. However, sometimes this website will append arguments such as `?postCount=25` or something to the end of the URL, so you get:

`example.com/example/anythinghere/?postCount=25`

Because of this, if I throw the current expression into a conditional, it will return false should there be URL arguments. How would I best go about changing the regex expression to allow for an *optional* URL argument wildcard, so that, if there's a question mark followed by any additional information, it will always return true, and, if it's omitted, it will still return true?

It would need to return true for:

`http://www.example.com/?argumentshere`

and

`http://www.example.com/example/anythinghere/?argumentshere`

As well as those same URLs *without* the extra arguments.

Comment: Drop the `?` before last, change `$` to `(\?|$)` (so the end looks like `...[^\/]+\/)?(\?|$)`

Comment: Works like a charm! If you'd like to make it an official answer, I'd be happy to extend the proper thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following regex:

```
^http:\/\/www\.example\.com(?:\/example\/[^\/]+\/?)?\??.*$
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/hU9rL4)

Comment: Will give it a try tomorrow and get back to you!

Answer (score 0):

You can build the URL without parameters and compare that with your current expression.

```
location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname
```

[How to get the URL without any parameters in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257463/how-to-get-the-url-without-any-parameters-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading my comment to an answer:

```
 /^http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/(?:example\/[^\/]+\/?)?$/;
```

Meanse:

```
 /^    # start of string
      http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/  #literal http://www.example.com/
      (?:           
         example\/[^\/]+\/? #followed by example/whatever (optionally closed by /)
      )?
      $ end-of-string
  /
```

The main problem here, is your requirements (*"followed by an optional querystring"*) does not match you regex (which requires an *end-of-string*). We solve it by:

```
 /^    # start of string
      http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/  #literal http://www.example.com/
      (?:           
         example\/[^\/]+\/? #followed by example/whatever (optionally closed by /)
      )?
      (\?|$) followed by either an end-of-string (original), or a literal `?` (which in url context means the rest is a query string and not a path anymore).
  /
```