# Removing query-string from url after other functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string

I'm not able to do it, i need to modify this script (thats works fine) and add a query string remove function at the end. In other words, when i click on a button link (.modal-close) i need to perform all the function (toggleClass, fadeOut...), wait 1 second and then remove query string from url.

the functions are:

```
 $(function() {
    $(".modal-close").click(function() {
        $("html").toggleClass("lightbox-is-open");
        $("html").toggleClass("lightbox-is-fixed");
        $(".dialog-container, .glasspane").fadeOut(200).addClass("hidden");
return false;
    });
  });
```

now, i need to remove the query strings, this would be fine?

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
```

I'm not able to combine all together.. (i'm a very dummy user).

my goal would be a code that's remove query string (".modal-close").click without reload the page, it's possible?

thanks

Comment: To my knowledge this is not possible.  Changing the query string will always trigger a new request.  Are you able to use `location.hash` instead (e.g. `http://www.example.com#modal`)?  Changing the hash does not trigger a new page request.

Comment: no, unfortunately i can't use hashes on my environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this question has already been answered several times before.  Your modified code may look like:

```
 $(function() {
    $(".modal-close").click(function() {
        $("html").toggleClass("lightbox-is-open");
        $("html").toggleClass("lightbox-is-fixed");
        $(".dialog-container, .glasspane").fadeOut(200).addClass("hidden");
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.href = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname;
        }, 200);
        return false;
    });
  });
```

Ref. [How to get the URL without any parameters in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257463/how-to-get-the-url-without-any-parameters-in-javascript)

Note: Code has not been tested.

Comment: There's a key difference though.  OP wants this functionality without causing a page refresh.

Comment: Ahh, sorry; I didn't catch that.  However, it seems that question, too, has been asked and answered before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700937/how-can-i-remove-the-query-string-from-the-url-after-the-page-loads Let my answer be a viable alternative if they wish to reconsider.

Comment: yeah, windows.location.href seems to work only with http requests.. i'm not able to find a way to do it without page reload

Comment: Yep. I think that history API post that you linked to is what they are looking for