# Reload iframe with different query parameters

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

On my webpage I have an iframe like:

> "https://localhost:4200/myroute/mypage.html?**name=batman&alias=bruce**

What I want is that when I click a button present on the iframe, the iframe reloads with new query parameters I specify (or pass to a function), say

> "https://localhost:4200/myroute/mypage.html?**name=superman&alias=clark**

I want the part before the query params to be unchanged; as I could have this iframe on multiple pages.

Is there any way to achieve this? I browsed through some [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86428/whats-the-best-way-to-reload-refresh-an-iframe-using-javascript) on SO, but that didn't help.

Thanks.

PS - I want the solution using pure javascript; no frameworks.

---

**EDIT**: I've temporarily gotten it to work with some help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28662284/3106343).

```
var fixedPath = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
window.location.href = `${fixedPath}?name=superman&alias=clark`
```

This reloads my iframe as required:

Problems: 
1) I've no idea if this code is good for different browsers. Or if it violates any good practices.

2) I have to pass all the param keys and values as a string; as against using it from an object like

```
{
    name: 'batman',
    alias: 'bruce',
}
```

Sure, I could traverse the object and store the keys and values in variables which I then use in my string. But that seems convoluted. Are there any APIs which would let me directly specify the value of a particular parameter?

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: @Krypton: see edit.

Comment: You can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525178/is-there-any-native-function-to-convert-json-to-url-parameters to get url parameters from a json object.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope, I guess I went with the approach outlined in the edit.