# how to remove a querystring on buttonclick?

Tags: jquery, url, query-string

how can i remove a querystring of an url when clicking a button? my url looks like this:

www.mysite.com/?tx_felogin_pi1[forgot]=1

this page shows a form for getting the new password, everything is inside an overlaybox. when the user suddenly remembers his userdata again, i need to provide a link in the box to go back to the signin form (also inside an overlaybox), but i can not use a fix url, because the link (and the overlaybox) should be accessable on every page. so i need a link which removes the querystring, independet of the url before.

i tried this, but it won't work:

```
    function getPathFromUrl(url) {
      return url.split("?")[0];
    }
    // from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540969/remove-querystring-from-url

    $("#querystring").click(getPathFromUrl);
```

the error in my console is: url.split is not a function...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What is `url`? You have to get the url from the `window.location` object:

```
$("#querystring").click(function(){
    window.location.href = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
});
```

Comment: it reloads the page.

Answer (score 2):

To get the url without querystring use this

```
function getPathFromUrl() {
  var url = window.location.href; 

  if(url.indexOf("?") != -1)
     url = url.split("?")[0];

  return url;
}
```

Usage

```
$("#querystring").click(function(){
     alert(getPathFromUrl());//this will alert the url without querystring
});
```

Comment: No need to ascertain that the string contains a `?`. `'test'.split('?')[0]` will return `test`.

Comment: Thats correct, but why to `split` of it does not contain '?'?

Comment: Because, although I did not test it, I doubt that `split` is more expensive than `indexOf` (besides for the fact that you'll most likely run them both). Why convolute your code like that?

Answer (score 1):

This will remove query string from URL.

Suppose your url is :-

`http://localhost:4567/projectName/abc.php?id=307`

Just replace the button class with your button's class and run this code for the page which you wants to remove query string.

```
    $(document).on('click',".button", function(){
    window.location.href = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname;    
    });
```

After run above code your url will be :-
`http://localhost:4567/projectName/abc.php`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#querystring").click(function(){
    // you can use url.split("?")[0]; here, however be sure it's in global scope

});
```