# why Request.Url includes querystring in it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, request

on one of my page, I let user to filter the content based on the age they choose from the age dropdown list.

here's my code.

```
$('#age').change(function () {
         var ageUrl = "@Request.Url?age=" + $(this).val();

         alert(ageUrl);
         window.location = ageUrl;
     });
```

here's the problem. I am on the app page.

http:// localhost:60627/apps

first time, I choose an age and get redirected , no problem.

http:// localhost:60627/apps?age=Middle_School

second time, I pick another one.

http:// localhost:60627/apps?age=Middle_School?age=Preschool

in the querystring, age showed up twice.  I tried both Request.Url or Request.RawUrl, always includes querystring.  what should I use to get only page url without querystring.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't really used this before but it does work:

```
 Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)
```

An alternative is:

```
 String.Format("{0}://{1}{2}",Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, Request.Url.LocalPath)
```

If you knew what controller/action you were on (from the ViewContext's data) you could use @Url.Action and specify the overload to force the http schema which would generate a full url as well.

Comment: Like the idea of using the URL.Action as that is more of a convention.

Comment: your code works, but there's another easier way, i replaced Request.Url with Request.Url.AbsolutePath

Comment: I agree that AbsolutePath works but you made it seem like you wanted the schema/authority prefix on your Urls for some reason. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try `Split` method of string?

```
Request.Url.ToString().Split('?')[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you building the URL yourself? Let MVC do it for you:

```
@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { age = "Preschool" })
```

If age is not part of the route then it will be automatically added to the query string:

```
http://localhost:12345/Controller/Action?age=Preschool
```

Comment: The problem with this code is his function is JavaScript and your code is all server side. Unless he was to use a placeholder token like !age! and replace the token with a value from the text box your example would work. Ex: var ageUrl = @Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { age = "!age!" })".replace('!age!',$(this).val());

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a property of Request, but it may provide a solution for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2541083/969829