# Get rid of characters in url href

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

I have a link like this:

```
http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandra_Stan&sa=U&ei=UULHUIIdzPnhBOKMgPgJ&ved=0CCIQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNGyCikDkoZMnnuqGo6vjMQ6b5lZkw
```

I would like to get rid of everything starting at '&' So this will give me a clean url:

```
http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandra_Stan
```

I know how to replace href like this:

```
$('a').each(function() {
      $(this).attr("href", function(index, old) {
            return old.replace("something", "something else");
      });
});
```

But I can't figure out how to get rid of everything starting at a certain character.

Comment: Please consider [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2541083/227646) answer on Stack Overflow. Never mind. Both the answers below are better suited than what I had.

Comment: is that even a valid URI without a `?` for the first qs param?

Comment: @jbabey What do you mean...It takes you to the page right?

Comment: @Youss if any server code (.NET, PHP, etc) attempts to retrieve any querystring values it will throw exceptions. The querystring portion of a URI must begin with `?`. [Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Structure)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `substr()` and `indexOf()` to get a specific portion of the URL, from the beginning of the URL string up until the point the first ampersand is encountered.

```
  var href = $(this).attr('href'); 
  var url = href.substr(0, href.indexOf('&'));
```

Comment: `String.prototype.indexOf` will not work if there is no '&' in the href!  It will return -1 and you will be left with empty string!

Comment: True, the OP should test for that.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) instead.  It splits a string by character into an array.  The most important part is that if that character is missing (in your case, '&'), it will put the entire string in the first array index anyway.

```
// String.prototype.indexOf:
var href = 'http://www.noAmpersandHere.com/',
    url  = href.substr(0, href.indexOf('&'));  // ''

// String.prototype.split:    
var href = 'http://www.noAmpersandHere.com/',
    url  = href.split('&');  // ['http://www.noAmpersandHere.com/']
    url  = url[0];  // 'http://www.noAmpersandHere.com/'
```

Comment: Would you care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

**First: consider that the parameters list starts with `?` and not with `&`**

The anchor element you are handling already have the entire url parsed and correctly divided.
You need only to access to the correct anchor property:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLAnchorElement