# How to remove query string ? from image url vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net, query-string

Whats the best way to remove a query string (the question mark variables) from a image url.

Say I got a good image such as
http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTYwMFgxNjAw/z/zoMAAOSwMpZUniWv/$_12.JPG?set_id=880000500F
But I can't really save it properly without adding a bunch of useless checking code because of the query string crap after it.

I just need
http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTYwMFgxNjAw/z/zoMAAOSwMpZUniWv/$_12.JPG

Looking for the proper regular expression that handles this so I could replace it with blank.

Comment: More answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540969/remove-querystring-from-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be simple enough not to worry about regex.

This would work:

```
Dim cleaned = url.Substring(0, url.IndexOf("?"c))
```

Comment: Thanks still need to wrap it with indexof conditional if-statement to check if ? even exists or it will error. That's why I perfer regex's but ya this seems better thanks I hear this is faster then regex too. (I judge from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540969/remove-querystring-from-url )