# Removing parameter values of a url in the next page using javascript only

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to remove the values from the url after the ? in the next page the moment i click from my first page. I tried a lot of coding but could not get to a rite path. Need help. 
The strings ex- Name, JobTitle and Date are dynamically generated values for ref.
Below are the links associated with the code:

**Required url**

> file:///C:/Users/varun.singh/Desktop/www%20updated%2027.8.2015%20Old/www/Candidates/newOne.html?

**Resultant url:**

> file:///C:/Users/varun.singh/Desktop/www%20updated%2027.8.2015%20Old/www/Candidates/newOne.html?Name=Name%201&JobTitle=Title%201&Date=Entered%20Date%201

```
listItem.onclick = function(){  


        var elementData=listData[this.id];
        var stringParameter= "Name=" + elementData.name +"&JobTitle="+elementData.job_title+"&Date="+ elementData.entered_date;

      //window.location.href = window.location.href.replace("ListCandidateNew", "newOne") + "?" + stringParameter;
       window.location.href="file:///C:/Users/varun.singh/Desktop/www%20updated%2027.8.2015%20Old/www/Candidates/newOne.html?"
                + stringParameter;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove querystring from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540969/remove-querystring-from-url)

Comment: just remove `+ stringParameter;` from href

Comment: The apporch you are using for maintaining URL is wrong. Try to maintain using Relative URLs.

Comment: i can not remove + stringParameter because it is required for the value passing name , Jobtitle and Date

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var url = file:///C:/Users/varun.singh/Desktop/www%20updated%2027.8.2015%20Old/www/Candidates/newOne.html?Name=Name%201&JobTitle=Title%201&Date=Entered%20Date%201

    var index = url.lastIndexOf("?");

    url = url.slice(0, index+1); // index+1 so that "?" is included
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everond for trying and attempting to answer my problem. Well, i have found the solution using window.sessionStorage as i wanted by keeping the string parameter alive to pass the values. Here is the full code:

I have two pages for passing the value from one to another: **ListCandidateNew.html and newOne.html**

**ListCandidateNew.html**

```js
    listItem.onclick = function() 
      { 
      
    
      var elementData=listData[this.id];
      var stringParameter= "Name=" + elementData.name +"&JobTitle="+elementData.job_title+"&Date="+ elementData.entered_date;
    
   
        window.sessionStorage['Name'] = elementData.name;
        window.sessionStorage['JobTitle'] = elementData.job_title;
     window.sessionStorage['Date'] = elementData.entered_date;

**newOne.html**

function LoadCandidateDetail()
 {  
    document.getElementById('Name').innerHTML = window.sessionStorage['Name'];
    document.getElementById('JobTitle').innerHTML = window.sessionStorage["JobTitle"];
       document.getElementById('Date').innerHTML = window.sessionStorage["Date"];
 }
```