# jQuery script wont add active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I got this jQuery script that's supposed to add the class "active" to my li's, but it doesn't. The script is as follows:

```
jQuery(function() {
 var pgurl = jQuery(location).attr('href');
 console.log(pgurl);
 jQuery("ul.pagesubmenu-ul li a").each(function(){
      if(jQuery(this).attr("href") == pgurl)
      jQuery(this).parent().addClass("active");
 })
```

});

I really don't know why it isn't working. I'm trying to use it on [this page](http://xn--fnpark-pua9l.dk/konference-ny/) (In the subnav below the main navigation).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure `href` attribute has similar url as `location` object, usually href tags doesn't contain domain names(for relative path)

Comment: First, check that the if condition will be executed. Check that in debug or add alert to if condition to be sure that the code jQuery(this).parent().addClass("active"); is executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not getting an exact match on any of those links. `pgurl` is showing `http://xn--fnpark-pua9l.dk/konference-ny/`, however the `<a>` tags don't have the trailing slash (`http://xn--fnpark-pua9l.dk/konference-ny`). Try cleaning up the url before comparing the strings. Here is a thread that will allow you to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2541083/5169684

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks a lot for your reply! I'm gonna mark this one as the correct one, as this is the reason it's not working :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I'd recommend you check into some of the other answers as well. The methods mentioned may make your code more readable in the long-run.

Comment: I'm gonna use the method taxicala suggested. Way cleaner and better than my own code! :)

Answer (score 4):

instead of looping all your links, you can directly select it with jquery by its href attribute:

```
$(function() {
    $("a[href='" + location.href + "']").parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Note that `location.href` will return the full url, with host and scheme, if you are using relative urls in your site:

```
$(function() {
    $("a[href='" + location.pathname + "']").parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Also, you can use some characters as wildcards:

```
= is exactly equal
!= not equal
^= starts with
$= ends with
*= contains
~= contains word
|= starts with prefix
```

Comment: Isn't regex legit here? Urls may contain search path( /link?q=test). Anyway u already got my +1,

Comment: thanks! i suppose regex would work as well, but it's not my strong :)

Comment: @taxicala - Thanks for your reply! I just tried using your script but I'm getting a error: unrecognized expression: a[href=http://xn--fnpark-pua9l.dk/konference-ny/]

Comment: Im sorry, i've forgot some quotes, i've updated my answer.

Comment: @taxicala - Thanks a lot! It works like a charm! I'm gonna be using this instead of my own script :)

Comment: No problem. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not working? Can you do a jsfiddle with your navigation structure...

HTML

`<ul class="page">
    <li><a href="1">Link</a>
        <ul class="subpage">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="2">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="3">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="4">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="5">Link</a></li>
</ul>`

JQUERY

`jQuery(function() {
     $("ul.page li ul.subpage li a").each(function(){
         $(this).addClass('active');
     });
 });`

https://jsfiddle.net/xp315ydq/