# How to remove a query string parameter from the url using jquery?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I am trying to loop through a few iframes to grab the src of the iframes and remove a particular query string from the src of those iframes. This is what I have so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('iframe').each(function() {
      var $src = $(this).attr('src').substring(0, $(this).attr('src').indexOf('&id'));
      alert($src);
   });
});
```

```css
iframe {
  width: 300px height:300px;
  background: #fafafa;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe src="mysite.com/program.asp?name=abc&status=3&id=2"></iframe>
<iframe src="mysite.com/program.asp?id=2"></iframe>
```

The first url of the iframe displays correctly but the second url of the second iframe does not.

The expected output:

```
first iframe - mysite.com/program.asp?name=abc&status=3
second iframe - mysite.com/program.asp?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove querystring from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540969/remove-querystring-from-url)

Comment: In the second function, the indexOf returns -1 so you're calculating substring(0, -1) which is an empty string. It seems normal it's not working

Comment: `this.src` should be accessable.  I don't know why you are doing jQuery there.

Comment: You're looking for specifically `&id=` but in the second, it's `?id=` - you need to use regex:  `[&?]id=` (or call replace twice).

Comment: You also have limited use cases, eg if you have : `?status=3&id=2&name=abc` then you should get `?status=3&name=abc` but you get `?status=3`.  I recommend just using one of the various options in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 11/7/2017 1:12PM**

I was able to answer my own question and figure it out but thank you for the help and comments. Here's the expected output I mentioned before. Thanks everyone.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('iframe').each(function() {
      if($(this).attr('src').indexOf('&id') > -1){
        var $src = $(this).attr('src').substring(0, $(this).attr('src').indexOf('&id'));
      }else{
        var $src = $(this).attr('src').substring(0, $(this).attr('src').indexOf('id'));
      }
      alert($src);
   });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('iframe').each(function() {
      if($(this).attr('src').indexOf('&id') > -1){
        var $src = $(this).attr('src').substring(0, $(this).attr('src').indexOf('&id'));
      }else{
        var $src = $(this).attr('src').substring(0, $(this).attr('src').indexOf('id'));
      }
      alert($src);
   });
});
```

```css
iframe {
  width: 300px height:300px;
  background: #fafafa;
  margin: 20px auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe src="mysite.com/program.asp?name=abc&status=3&id=2"></iframe>
<iframe src="mysite.com/program.asp?id=2"></iframe>
```