# Regular expression with Variable

Tags: javascript

Im trying to remove the 'page=?' (? = only numbers) from URL path with following method:

```
var urlslugRegex = '/^[a-z0-9-]+$/';
var url = window.location.href;
var lastpath = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
var lasturl = lastpath.replace('page=' + urlslugRegex, '');
```

but the regular expression not working. Any ideas?

Comment: your regex is a string

Comment: also consider using `URL` instead.

Comment: Are you tyring to remove the *entire* querystring? If so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540969/remove-querystring-from-url

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with jQuery, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

```
var urlslugRegex = '/^[a-z0-9-]+$/';
var url = window.location.href;
var lastpath = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
var lasturl = lastpath.replace('page=' + urlslugRegex, '');
```

The regex which is being sent to replace() function is

> page=/^[a-z0-9-]+$/

I hope, this is not what you wanted.

You can fix it by simply by

> var lasturl = lastpath.replace(/^page=[a-z0-9-]+$/, '');