# JavaScript string .replace for URL

Tags: javascript

I scrape sites for a database with a chrome extension,
need assitance with a JavaScript Clean up function

e.g

https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/_60789694386.html?spm=a2700.galleryofferlist.normalList.1.5be41470uWBNGm&s=p

my target output is:

_60789694386.html

everything past .html needs to be removed, but since it is diffrent in each URL - i'm lost

the output is in a .csv file, in which i run a JavaScript to clean up the data.

```
   this.values[8] = this.values[8].replace("https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/","");
```

this.values[8] is how i target the column in the script. (Column 8 holds the URL)

Comment: you could split at `?` and get the first bit. `yourString.split('?')[0]` ?

Comment: This could be helpful **[Remove query string]** [https://stackoverflow.com/remove-querystring-from-url ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540969/remove-querystring-from-url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can use `split`.

```js
var final = this.values[8].split('.html')[0]
```

`split` gives you an array of items split by a string, in your case`'.html'`, then you take the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```
this.values[8] = this.values[8].substr(0,this.values[8].indexOf('?'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split method to divide text from ? as in example.

```js
var link = "https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/_60789694386.html?spm=a2700.galleryofferlist.normalList.1.5be41470uWBNGm&s=p"
var result = link.split('?')[0].replace("https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/","");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understood your problem, but try this

```js
var s = 'https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/_60789694386.html?spm=a2700.galleryofferlist.normalList.1.5be41470uWBNGm&s=p'
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('?'));
console.log( s );
```

Answer (score 0):

For when you don't care about readability...

```
this.values[8] = new URL(this.values[8]).pathname.split("/").pop().replace(".html","");
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate, without using split

```js
var link = "https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/_60789694386.html?spm=a2700.galleryofferlist.normalList.1.5be41470uWBNGm&s=p"
var result = link.replace('https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/', '').replace(/\?.*$/, '');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex to get it done. As of my knowledge you do something like:

```
    var v = "https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/_60789694386.html?spm=a2700.galleryofferlist.normalList.1.5be41470uWBNGm&s=p"
    result = (v.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0]);
    result = result.substring(0,result.indexOf('?'));
    console.log(result);    // will return _60789694386.html
```